# Resolving dynamic libraries dependencies when loading with dlopen()

Tags: c, linux, dlopen

I faced a problem with loading a dynamic library with `dlopen()`:
I attempt to load a library:

```
handle = dlopen("libmkl_intel_lp64.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

This code fails with the following message from `dlerror()`:

`/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so: undefined symbol: mkl_vsl_serv_threader_for`

I know that this symbol can be found in another library, `libmkl_gnu_thread.so` for example. If use `LD_PRELOAD` to load that library the above mentioned error on undefined symbol goes away. But how do I make this symbol available without using `LD_PRELOAD`?

In case of explicit linking I would list all the libraries but I'm not sure what the logic is in my case of using `dlopen()`

Comment: Just dlopen that other library beforehand with RTLD_GLOBAL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a dependency to your .so file. These dependencies are shown with the `ldd` command. They are added in several ways - most common is when compiling your .so, add `-l<dep>` to add a dependency to `<dep>.so`  .