# Can't compile package with intel MKL ScaLapack and Blacs

Tags: python, c, mpi, intel-mkl, scalapack

I am trying to compile python package https://github.com/jrs65/scalapy which wraps `mkl` `scalapack` and `blacs` libraries. Compilation is successful however when I try to execute test programs I get:

> Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load symbol MKLMPI_Get_wrappers

I tried to use `mkl_link_tool` to get linking lines.
This is what is happening under the hood of `distutils`:

```sh
gcc -pthread -shared -L/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/intelpython3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/intelpython3/lib,--no-as-needed -z noexecstack -z relro -z now -fstack-protector build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/scalapy/lowlevel/redistmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/scalapy/lowlevel/fortranobject.o -L/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/intelpython3/lib -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/scalapy/lowlevel/redist.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -I/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mpi/intel64/include -L/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/release_mt -L/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mpi/intel64/lib -Xlinker --enable-new-dtags -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/release_mt -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mpi/intel64/lib -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /opt/intel/mpi-rt/2107.0.0/intel64/lib/release_mt -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /opt/intel/mpi-rt/2017.0.0/intel64/lib -lmpifort -lmpi -lmpigi -ldl -lrt -lpthread -L/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mkl/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_scalapack_lp64 -lmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl -fopenmp
```

I also tried static linking with `-Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group -Wl,-Bdynamic`:

```sh
gcc -pthread -shared -L/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/intelpython3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/intelpython3/lib,--no-as-needed -z noexecstack -z relro -z now -fstack-protector build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/scalapy/lowlevel/redistmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/scalapy/lowlevel/fortranobject.o -L/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/intelpython3/lib -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/scalapy/lowlevel/redist.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -I/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mpi/intel64/include -L/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/release_mt -L/scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mpi/intel64/lib -Xlinker --enable-new-dtags -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/release_mt -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mpi/intel64/lib -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /opt/intel/mpi-rt/2107.0.0/intel64/lib/release_mt -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /opt/intel/mpi-rt/2017.0.0/intel64/lib -lmpifort -lmpi -lmpigi -ldl -lrt -lpthread -Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,--start-group /scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_lp64.a /scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.a /scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a /scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a /scratch/apc/lukrazi/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.148/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-Bdynamic -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl -fopenmp
```

No success. What could be the problem?

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201860/resolving-dynamic-libraries-dependencies-when-loading-with-dlopen , try adding all relevant MKL libraries to `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: Suggest you run `nm` of the shared object, and check if the symbol `MKLMPI_Get_wrappers` is presetned. `nm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/scalapy/lowlevel/redist.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep MKLMPI_Get_wrappers`. It will provide a hint if this is build is or runtime issue

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: a) build a shared library via

`-ld -shared --whole-archive libmkl_blacs_openmpi_lp64.a -no-whole-archive -o libmkl_blacs_openmp_lp64.so`

or b) link to static libraries by adding

```
-Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,--start-group
```

and

```
-Wl,--end-group -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Comment: Source URL: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/590302